# How to set Initial value to a texfeild from shared prefrences

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a textfeild i want to set the initial value  (user email) from sharedPrefrences , but the problem is my sharedPrefrences function is of future type ,So on initState function the initial value is assigning null because as you all know future function take its time.How can i do it.

```
class Checkout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckoutState createState() => _CheckoutState();
}

class _CheckoutState extends State<Checkout> {
  String emailCheck = "";

  profileData() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      emailCheck = preferences.getString("email");
    });

    return emailCheck;
  }


  TextEditingController email;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    profileData();
    email = TextEditingController(text: "$emailCheck");


  }
```

and this is my textfeild

```
 subtitle: TextField(
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),

                  hintText: "1278 Loving Acres Road Kansas City, MO 64110",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                maxLines: 1,
                controller: email,
              ),
```

Comment: if you have `Future` data use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: @pskink i am new to flutter can you show me a code snippet ,i don't know how to assign future builder to a textfeild , and the thing here is i  am initializing data to textfeild which i am doing outside of builders,so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a text edit controller then pass text in **profileData** function.

For example:

```dart
var emailController = TextEditingController();

  profileData() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String emailCheck = preferences.getString("email");
    setState(() {
      if(emailCheck.isNotEmpty){
        currencyController.text = emailCheck;
      }
    });
  }


@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    profileData();
  }
```

Comment: You are a life saver, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Set the initial value to a default value (for instance empty string), then call asynchronously your method which accesses shared preferences, and when it's done then set the value to the newly retrieved value, using setState(). It's a good exercise to learn how Flutter works.